# Contar contactos de un json en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

Tengo este JSON y quisiera poder contar los contactNumber que contiene

en mi SQLServer solo me aparecen 3 opciones ISJSON, JSON_VALUE Y JSON_QUERY

como puedo hacerlo solo en SQL???

[{"contactId":"1029","contactNumber":"+49 151 14559868"},{"contactId":"1031","contactNumber":"+49 174 2867772"},{"contactId":"1029","contactNumber":"+4915114559868"},{"contactId":"1049","contactNumber":"+49174 2486274"},{"contactId":"1049","contactNumber":"+491742486274"},{"contactId":"1031","contactNumber":"+491742867772"},{"contactId":"1024","contactNumber":"+52 5516842646"},{"contactId":"1039","contactNumber":"+52 5528557607"},{"contactId":"1035","contactNumber":"+52 5531029252"},{"contactId":"1044","contactNumber":"+52 5532334663"},{"contactId":"1048","contactNumber":"+52 5534767746"},{"contactId":"1038","contactNumber":"+52 5537318151"},{"contactId":"1033","contactNumber":"+52 5540802725"},{"contactId":"1043","contactNumber":"+52 5541933765"},{"contactId":"1051","contactNumber":"+52 5543465096"},{"contactId":"1052","contactNumber":"+52 5544559047"},{"contactId":"1041","contactNumber":"+52 5548605001"},{"contactId":"1050","contactNumber":"+52 5548704331"},{"contactId":"1046","contactNumber":"+52 5548900690"},]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un Select con un OPENJSON declarando que quieres obtener contactNumber como un varchar, y ya una vez tratado como tabla, pues puedes contar el numero de resultados, mas o menos asi

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

set @JSON ='[{"contactId":"1029","contactNumber":"+49 151 14559868"},"contactId":"1031","contactNumber":"+49 174 2867772"}]';

SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$')
    WITH(
        contactNumber VARCHAR(50)
    ) as R
```

Tomando en cuenta claro que @JSON sea un string de tu Json, y que este tiene que estar bien formateado.

Respondiento a el comentario, trate de esta manera usando STRING_SPLIT para tratar el resultado como su fuera una tabla, haciendo split por el inicio del objeto { y preparandolo para obtener el valor con JSON_VALUE. Creo que esta un poquito enredosa la query.

```
SELECT COUNT(JSON_VALUE(R.result,'$.contactNumber')) FROM (SELECT '{' + SUBSTRING(value,0,LEN(VALUE)) as result FROM STRING_SPLIT(@json,'{') WHERE Value <> '') as R
WHERE ISJSON(R.result) = 1
```

dejo una captura de lo que me resulto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me sale un error con OPENJSON

El nombre de objeto 'OPENJSON' no es válido.

por eso mencione que solo tengo  3 opciones ISJSON, JSON_VALUE Y JSON_QUERY

Comment: Esta raro que puedas trabajar con json desde sql server pero no puedas usar las demas funciones, de cualquier manera, te deje otra forma que fui calando para que saliera, aunque queda un poquillo enredosa. a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Al `json` para `sqlServer`, igual le sobra la última coma. Para poder mejorar el escenario puedes utilizar `select @@version` y buscar el compatibility level de la bbdd, y editar la pregunta para ir completándola. Aunque la respuesta que te han proporcionado es buena, si aún mantienes problemas con `Json`. lo que pides no, es más que contar filas por un string con un separador. `Select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@JSON,',')fn where fn.Item like'"contactNumber"%'. [Separar](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Comment: Adicional: `Json_Value`, trabaja con un `NVarChar` como máximo de 4000 caracteres, y si excede puede devolver null o error, en función del modo [Json_value doc oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). `OpenJson`, solo funciona en un nivel de compatibilidad 130 (SQL 2016). [OpenJson doc oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)